# How to use "apply" function with 2 condition in R?

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a string variable in dataframe and want to delete some rows that contain strings like "A" or "B". I used these codes but they didn't work :

```
isna=apply(DATA[1], 2, function(x)x!="A"|"B")

isna=apply(DATA[1], 2, function(x)x!="A"||"B")
```

Comment: Could you add a sample of your dataframe? give us `head(DATA)`

Comment: DATA[1]=c(A,B,C,C,A,D) @dmi3kno

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is there a reason you need to use apply?

```
DATA <- data.frame(code=sample(LETTERS[1:5],10, replace = TRUE))
subset(DATA, code!="A" & code!="B")
```

Comment: No, but I didn't know that I can use subset in this case. Thanks, its working !

Answer (score 1):

if I understood what you need correctly, then this is also an option:

```
library(dplyr)

# an exemplary dataframe 
df <- data.frame(col1 = sample(LETTERS[1:5], 20, replace = TRUE), 
             col2 = 1:20)
df

# the filter for choosing the rows
filter(df, !col1 %in% c("A", "B"))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
isna=apply(DATA[1], 2, function(x)(x!="A")&(x!="B"))
DATA <- DATA[isna,]
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/19612350)

Comment: @vonbrand yes you're right I understood, i commented now and use it more in future cases.